# what are bvp5c and bvp4c in matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, boundary-value-problem

In ode's command in matlab software, I want to know that what is the difference between these two commands in matlab. bvp4c and bvp5c 
Regards
Nima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation,](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html)

> The bvp5c function is used exactly like bvp4c, with the exception of the meaning of error tolerances between the two solvers. If $S(x)$ approximates the solution $y(x),$ bvp4c controls the residual $|S'(x) – f(x,S(x))|.$ This controls indirectly the true error $|y(x) – S(x)|.$ bvp5c controls the true error directly.

Comment: So one should always use bvp5c?